# How to commit and push with simple-git (NODEJS)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, github, gitlab

I'm trying to do a simple Commit & Push to an existing repo using `simple-git` however I can't find
any example regarding this issue in the API in NPM (or Github) of `simple-git`.

I'm talking about this package : https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-git

Consider the code :

```
const gitRepo = 'REPO-URL';
const tempFolder = '...';


// Simple Git
const simpleGit = require('simple-git')();

const options = ['--depth', '1'];
const callback = () => {
    console.log('Done cloning!');      
    // Now change some code in the cloned code 
    // and commit && push 
};

// Cloning ...
simpleGit.outputHandler((command, stdout, stderr) => {
    stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
    stderr.pipe(process.stderr)

    stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        // Print data
        console.log(data.toString('utf8'));})
    })
    .clone(gitRepo, tempFolder, options, callback);
```

How can we commit and push using `simple-git` ?

Comment: rtm there is `.commit("...").push('origin', 'master');` methods

Comment: @LawrenceCherone: Commit & Push must be done after cloning and updating the cloned repo (with new changes), this is not possible with your solution.

Comment: actually, a quick look at the doc there is various ways/examples to do a clone, make a change, commit and push, why are you using simpleGit.outputHandler( and not a promise chain or async/await?

Answer (score 0):

Like @Lawrence Cherone said :

You can just use the basic commands as is.

This is how i used it in my project ( though i got a submodule in it where this example is changing its (git)working directory to content(submodule) first. After that i just commit with a message.

```
app.post("/gitCommit", async function(req, res) {
  try {
    await git.cwd({ path: 'content' }).commit(req.body.msg);    
    res.sendStatus(200)
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
});
```

If you already have a working and initialised repo your in,
then you could just do the following:

- await git.commit("your_message")
- await git.push()
- await git.push('origin', 'master')

You can leave out the 'await' part depending on your code running async.

Comment: Your answer wors on localhost but not on the server